# How to remove error notice of application.properties in Spring tool suite (STS)

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-tool-suite

[image]

As shown in the picture, there is an error mark of application.properties.

However, the error in the application.properties is like :

`a=${b}`

and a is supposed to be a boolean property, but here is a just a reference and b is a remote config key.

How do I remove the error mark and keep it hidden forever (delete is useless).

Comment: keeping that line you want to remove the error mark?

Comment: Disable this kind of validation at project level.

Comment: What version of STS are you using? I tried this with STS 4.0.1 and it doesn't give an error when a property's value contains anything resembling a `${..}` placeholder. (I tried this: `spring.jmx.enabled=${a}`).